# Sorting a List of Objects by a List of Objects

Tags: list, sorting, object

I have a list of "Person" objects. A Person object contains the following properties...

```
Public Class Person
     Public Property Name As String
     Public Property Age As Integer
     Public Property ValueList as List(of Integer)
End Class
```

Each of the Person objects in the list will always have the same number of Integers in their ValueList property. That number needs to be able to vary though. So at one time all of them will have 3 Integers in the list, at another time they all would have 2 Integers.

My question is, how would I go about sorting the objects first by their "Age" property, then by the first Integer in ValueList, then the next Integer in ValueList, and so on?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this as really just a normal sorting problem that you would see with say sorting names. When sorting you must compare values. When sorting names alphabetically the first letter would be compared (this can be thought of as the age), and then the second, third, fourth letter (ValueList) until the values are not equal to each other. I think the cleanest way to go about sorting your list of Persons is write a sorting algorithm and when two Persons need to be compared, pass them into a comparison method that will return zero, a negative number, or a positive number based on which Person is "greater".

I put down some pseudocode for an insertion sort (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) below. What is bold is specific to your situation.

```
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    x ← A[i]
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and **fooCompareMethod(A[j-1], x) > 0**
        A[j] ← A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    A[j] ← x

//Returns positive if person1 is "greater than" person2
//return negative if person1 is "less than" person2
//returns zero if person1 and person2 are "equal"
**int fooCompareMethod(person1, person2) 
    if person1 Age > person2 Age
        return 1
    else if person1 Age < person2 Age
        return -1
    else
        for k ← 1 to length(person1 ValueList) //assuming both valueLists are same length
            y ← person1 ValueList(k)
            z ← person2 ValueList(k)
            if y > z
                return 1
            else if y < z
                return -1
    return 0**
```

Comment: I found a way using LINQ to get things done...

This is what I came up with.

    Function GenerateOrder(ByVal pList As List(Of Person), ByVal valueCount As Integer) As List(Of Person)
        Dim tempList = pList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Age)        
    
        For i = valueCount - 1 To 0           
            tempList = tempList.ThenBy(Function(x) x.ValueList(i))
        Next
    
        Return tempList.ToList()
    End Function